# Opacity keeps increasing with each call

Tags: javascript, signalr, kineticjs

I'm working on a project where I combined KineticJS with SignalR to update the stage on server calls.

So far everything works pretty good, and for the things that didn't work I had great help with the questions and answers on SO.

However this time I can't get it to work I also can't find any questions with a similar problem.

Basically I'm dynamically generating the init script for the KineticJS stage.(this all works perfectly) the code output looks like this:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    id: 1,
    container: 'stage-container',
    width: self.baseWidth,
    height: self.baseHeight
});
```

And for a shape it looks like this:

```
var shape129 = new Kinetic.Line({
    id: 'shape129',
    points: [249,66, 1889,66, 1889,928, 249,928, 249,66],
    fill: '#DADADA',
    opacity: 1,
    stroke: '#3B5A99',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    closed: true,
    draggable: true
});
```

So far so good.

It all renders perfectly.

Then the magic happens and I use a SignalR method to change the color of the shape
With the following code I get perfect color switches but not the desired opacity:

```
signal.client.statuschange = function (id, message) {
    var shape = Kinetic.stages[0].find('#' + id);
    shape.setAttr('fill', message);
    shape.setOpacity(0.5);
    shape.getLayer().draw();
};
```

As I said the color changes perfectly but the opacity keeps increasing with each call to the method.

I'm kinda lost here and not sure what is happening and most of all Why it is happening.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is the shape automatically cleared by Kinetic before draw? Otherwise, constant redrawing without clearing previous graphics would add up and you would get the effect you're describing. P.S. I'm not familiar with Kinetic so my assumptions could be wrong.

Comment: I don't know much about kinetikJS and SignalR but the "increasing opacity" thing makes me think that maybe you're not clearing the canvas on each frame and so the shapes overlap and the opacity increases.

Comment: I'm not making a new shape tho. I'm just updating an already existing shape. Also I'm not sure how I would be clearing the previous graphics. Since that is never done in the tutorials e.g. [html5canvastutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-set-alpha-with-kineticjs/)

Comment: Also worth noting: When I trigger a stage redraw(with a shape movement by mouse for example) the entire stage gets redrawn and all shapes shortly appear with the right opacity and the right color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem in `find` function. Your `shape` is not a node, but a collection. Try this:

```
var shape = Kinetic.stages[0].find('#' + id)[0];
```